# Do we have a concept of dangling object in C++

Tags: c++, new-operator, free

I was just thinking what happens when we use `free()` with `new` in C++.

In case if we use `free()` with `new` then the memory could be freed. Its just the destructor will not be called. Leaving behavior something like similar to dangling pointer.

I understand that above we should not use `free()` with `new` as it may corrupt the heap.

But then also I would like to visualize the behavior conceptually.

Comment: "I was just thinking what happens when we use free() with new() in C++." Nothing meaningful. It's undefined behaviour. There's simply no reason to even bother with it.

Comment: I haven't  heard a specific term for the situation you describe. I would just expect someone to say that the memory was reclaimed but the destructor didn't fire...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `free` on memory allocated by `new` is undefined behavior.  There's no guarantee that `new` returns an address returned from `malloc`.  (In fact, `new[]` often doesn't.)

Comment: +1, there is no guarantee that the memory came from `malloc` at all!

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to mix these at all. `new` and `delete` are paired up just as `malloc` and `free` are.

Remember that the behavior of `new` can be completely re-defined by the application and can use an allocation strategy that has nothing to do with the heap at all. It's because of this that you can't depend on `free` to be able to do anything at all with pointers generated by `new`. They're two different worlds.

Comment: I think he knows that, he just wants to know if there's a specific term for that situation.

Comment: @Doug the term is undefined behaviour.

Comment: That's the general term for things that may work by sheer chance, but shouldn't be done because they're a *bad idea*.